# Application List View

Tags: lists, grid, applications, view

I wanted help in designing the Applications List view. We have different applications that are grouped under categories. Eg: Social media - Skype, Slack etc.

**Box Grid**
[image]

In this view we have white boxes that show groupings of applications under each category.The cards can be collapsed and moved around. 
Disadvantage - Lot of boxes can be visually overwhelming information to users

**Second Option**
[image]

In this view ,users are greeted by list sort of pattern where categories 
are aligned one after other. Only disadvantage is lot of space gets unutilized.

Each category would be having approx 4~6 apps. So wanted suggestions on best approach or something better.

Comment: What does this list do? Could you please add what happens when a user selects an application? Are there additional options to remove or rearrange them? Do the applications open within the same frame? Is there a page which displays additional details about a selected application?

Comment: How many categories are being considered here approximately?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some thoughts, with the caveat that I don't really know who your customers are or how they're going to use this shortcut system.

--

People are used to screens being populated with icons, think desktops, or app browsing on iOS/Android, I think this is fine.

If you're designing this to be responsive, then I suspect you're going to end up using both patterns anyway.

IMO, having the slim view on a larger viewport is a waste of real estate, but you'll need that view if you are going to translate this to a mobile device.

Automatically closing accordions if they're hunting for something is annoying. Give them a mechanism for searching for an App through the name and extra meta-data right at the top of the page.

Unless all your users are going to be using all the applications all of the time, then perhaps giving them the ability to create their own group of apps might be the answer. I don't know your use-case but if you give them the ability to create their own groups, then they could have something like:

- [Apps I use all the time]
- [sometimes useful]
- [Everything else, might be useful at another time]

Better yet, give them a list of all the apps, then when you have a better understanding of their usage, (eg: After they "run/open" an app) add it to a list/group of recently used apps at the top, so they no longer have to hunt for something you know they use.